# XMPP sampler not found in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have installed jmeter and it's extension, copy lib extension jar to jmeter lib and extension-->lib-->extension to jmeter-->lib-->extension
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPSet/

i have found xmpp connection config but couldn't find the xmpp sampler, am new to jmeter.

i need xmpp sampler

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPSampler/

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to install a JMeter plugin using [Plugin-Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

1. First, Install Plugin-Manager. download the jar and keep in `/lib/ext` folder of JMeter and restart the JMeter.
2. From JMeter GUI, go to `Options -> Plugin-Manager` which displayes already installed plugin, available plugins, and the plugins which have new versions to upgrade. select the checkbox related to `XMPP protocol support` to install XMPP plugin.

---

Another way is which you followed.

1. Download the zip file (contain jars) from [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-xmpp)
2. Extract it to a folder. it contains `lib` folder and `ext` folder (inside lib folder) with jars.
3. Move the jars under `lib` folder from the unzipped file to JMeter `lib` folder.
4. Move the jars under `ext` folder from the unzipped file to JMeter `ext` folder.
5. Start jmeter.bat/jmeter.sh file.
6. XMPP Config Element and XMPP samplers will be available as `bzm - XMPP Connection` & `bzm - XMPP Sampler`

Comment: I tried with JMeter 3.0 and it worked for me (both sampler and config element is shown). what is the version that you tried?